Was Sirius unaware that on every Death Eaters' arm there is the Dark Mark?
When Harry told Sirius about the incident of Karkaroff showing Snape something on his arm, Sirius said that he had no idea what can it mean.

"Yeah, you should've seen Snape's face when Karkaroff turned up in
Potions yesterday!" said Harry quickly. "Karkaroff wanted to talk to
Snape, he says Snape's been avoiding him. Karkaroff looked really
worried. He showed Snape something on his arm, but I couldn't see what
it was."
He showed Snape something on his arm?" said Sirius, looking frankly
bewildered. He ran his fingers distractedly through his filthy hair,
then shrugged again. "Well, I've no idea what that's about...but if
Karkaroff's genuinely worried, and he's going to Snape for answers..."

Sirius fought in the first wizarding war as an active member of Order of Phoenix. Did the order not know the basic marks of death eaters in the first war?

Potentially was just lying? Adults do that to Harry a lot.

It's unlikely, and I don't remember the Death Eater status at this time (I'm assuming this was Order of the Phoenix?), it's possible he just didn't make the connection at that time or didn't want to believe it was the Dark Mark.

Another probability is that it is a JKR slip-up.

@Daemons I would say Goblet of Fire, during the Christmas ball?
I was suspecting readers' buildup to the reveal of the mark. But I don't know if it's talked about when the death eaters attack the Quidditch World Cup. If not, it's either Sirius lying, or a JKR slip-up. Since Sirius rather wants to tell the the trio everything, Sirius shutting up about it feels out of character.
